# stock messages app not showing country code in "Send To" called using Intent call?

Tags: android, android-intent, country-codes, mobile-country-code, android-messaging

I am creating an android app. It having a function that, if the user clicks a button it will open the messaging app with recipient number with country code.

The Intent call which includes country code also. But the destination stock messaging app not displaying country code of my country if the mobile's country code belongs to my country.

But it displaying country code, if the code belongs to outer countries.

**My Intent Call:**

```
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+countryCode+destmobile));
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Here if the `countrycode` variable contains a foreign country code, then messaging app showing the country code along the mobile number

But if the country code contains a number of my own country, the country code not displaying in message app and only the number is showing.

Why this issue happing ? What are the steps to resolve it .

Comment: retreive country code using locale and try sending it using the intent

Comment: is the contact of ur country already in ur contact list???